# Error on prediction in Logistic Regression

Tags: r, logistic-regression

Im performing logistic regression on a given dataset after splitting the data into train and test split. Classification works. While doing prediction Im getting the error

> "Error in model.frame.default(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.action,
> xlev = object$xlevels) :    factor Decoration has new levels 13, 15"

I checked and found that Decoration has values 13,15 in test but not in Train.

This same issue is happening in multiple columns. How to fix this?

Comment: how did you split the data ?

Comment: Samet's question is important.  You need to split the data in a way that preserves the factor levels of the entire dataset.

Comment: I split the data using the below code

library(caTools)
set.seed(12)
split = sample.split(ds2$Recommendation,SplitRatio = 75)
training_set = subset(ds2,split == TRUE)
test_set = subset(ds2, split == FALSE)

Comment: I tried different split ratios. I also tried deleted the data with certain values for columns appearing only once. After that , I found that certain data is still appearing only in test and not in train.

Comment: @Brian, how else can we do this split?

Comment: Try `caret::createDataPartition`.  I believe it does stratified random samples within the different factor levels.